# SDL Tridion taxonomy component count is off

Tags: tridion, taxonomy, tridion-content-delivery

I am new to Tridion and am facing an issue with the taxonomy.

As storage we are using file system and for taxonomy we have sql db.

Now, we have created **State** as Category with few keywords inside it. I have created schema and a component and have selected one of the keyword for classification. This associates the keyword with the component.

Now I have used the Tridion control with the uri of the **State** to retreive the taxonomy. It works fine, but the component count is showing as (0) instead of (1) since only one component is added in the bracket which is the normal behavior of tridion. I have published the taxonomy as well as the component.

Comment: When you say 'published the taxonomy' does that mean you clicked on the 'Category' inside tridion and published it?   Can you confirm that taxonomy exists in the sql database?

Comment: also check you are publishing from right publication..

Comment: It looks like you're trying to retrieve the number of components that match a given keyword. Could you share your content delivery code for this call?

Comment: Alvin, This is the code in my TBB - <tridion:TaxonomyControl ID="tax"  TaxonomyURI="tcm:13-245-512" runat="server">
      </tridion:TaxonomyControl>

Comment: Vikas and John -  I have a single publication and it's publishing correctly in my sql.

Comment: If you add the showEmptyKeywords to your  tridion:TaxonomyControl does it show your item(s) with zero? - this could help show there is a problem with the numbering code rather than your publishing. Are you sure that the content related to that taxonomy is also published?  I know you say you have, but other than a publishing mix up (e.g items to different targets, the component is failing to publish etc), I cannot see what this would be.

Comment: Hi, did you get get a solution to this?

Comment: Thanks for asking, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 4):

You need to publish the Component that is using the Keyword. As far as I can see, the control is counting items on the Content Delivery side; not items in the Content Manager. I set up a simple example using the basic tag:

```
<tridion:TaxonomyControl 
    ID="taxBasicProperties" 
    TaxonomyURI="tcm:1-8-512" 
    runat="server">
</tridion:TaxonomyControl>
```

Result without the component published:

- Sistema operativo (0)

  - Android (0)
  - iOS (0)
  - Windows (0)

Result **WITH** component published:

- Sistema operativo (1)

  - Android (0)
  - iOS (0)
  - Windows (1)